# magento patch9767 payment order issue

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-9767

After installing the patch-9767 I am unable to move to the next step from payment information in onepage checkout page.

Comment: hi @shiva let me know the exact error or console log error u are getting?

Comment: hi @NAGARAJUKASA its worked for me find the blelow Answer

Answer (score 1):

Your custom theme templates are most likely missing the form key update.

To fix that, I suggest you run the following script: https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b